# Storing integer as attribute in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I want to pass an `Integer` value as an attribute in JSP. But when i try

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(request.getAttribute("count"));
```

an error is returned. Could you tell me a method to store `Integer` numbers as attributes in JSP?

I am getting a casting error saying `parseInt()` is not suited for handling objects.

Comment: You should post the exceptions.

Comment: Are you using a capital R?

Comment: The exception is :                                                  The method parseInt(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (Object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request.getAttribute` returns an Object. you need to cast this to `String` like this:

```
Integer.parseInt((String)request.getAttribute("count"));
```

Comment: I tried that but then we get the ASCII value of the string and not the integer which we need to use.

Comment: Show us where you put the parameter into the request.

Comment: int num=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("action"));
  ReadExcel readExcel = new ReadExcel();
  String[] names = readExcel.readExcelSheet("D:/test1.xls",num,1);
  String[] images= readExcel.readExcelSheet("D:/test1.xls", num,2);
  String[] desc= readExcel.readExcelSheet("D:/test1.xls", num,3);
  request.setAttribute("desc", desc);
  request.setAttribute("img", images);
  request.setAttribute("vid", names);
  **request.setAttribute("count", 0);**
  
 }

Comment: @user2411994 then you do `Integer myCount =  (Integer) request.getAttribute("count");`

Answer (score 0):

To access the request in a JSP use `request` with a lowercase r.  It also needs to be in a scriptlet, however the use of scriptlets is not advised since you can easily use JSP EL.

```
<%
     int i=Integer.parseInt((String)request.getAttribute("count"));
%>
```

If you are displaying this value on the page, you can easily use the expression language:

`${count}`

Comment: Yes. I am using it inside scriplets. But still not working. And no i'm not displaying the value. I have to use this value as an array count.

Comment: Post the exception, please.

Comment: The method parseInt(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (Object)

Answer (score 0):

request.getAttribute() - returns an Object.

So this object has to be typecasted as follows

**int i = (Integer.parseInt)(String.valueOf(request.getAttribute("count")));**

I have working example with me..have a look

String Balance =  (String.valueOf(session.getAttribute("CostOfTotalTicket")));

int i = Integer.parseInt(Balance);

where **CostOfTotalTicket** variable i have stored in session is of **String** type

Comment: Nope. That doesn't work. It is giving a "Integer.parseInt cannot be resolved to a type" error

Comment: Can you tell me dataType of "count" variable??

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%Object object = request.getAttribute("count");
    int val =Integer.parseInt(object.toString());%>
```

it's working for me

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of data type you need to send, for this example I 'm sending data of `integer` type.

in the first servlet:

```
request.setAttribute("count", count);  //To send data
```

in the second servlet:

```
request.getAttribute("count"); //To receive data
```

this worked for me.